# ZK onMouseOver event in a Listbox is not being captured

Tags: listbox, mouseover, zk

I have seen [this question asked in the ZK Forum](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/62704/mouseover-event-in-zk-listbox-open-new-popup-window/) and I am trying to do pretty much the same.

I have a renderer in which

```
 /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void render(Listitem item, Object o, int index) throws Exception
    {

        Listcell cell = new Listcell();
        ComponentsCtrl.applyForward(cell, "onMouseOver=onMouseOverListCell");
        cell.setParent(item);
        .....
```

And in my controller I have

```
public void onMouseOverListCell(Event event) throws Exception   {
       System.out.println("There was an event :->" + event.getName());
       Component component = event.getTarget(); //      
       Listcell lc = (Listcell) event.getTarget(); //     
       System.out.println(lc.getLabel().toString());
```

}

The issue is that it doesn't get called. If I change the method name to onMouseOver, it does get called but mouseover's from all over the page are being sent there and the parent is the Window rather than the ListCell as expected.

Could someone please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a example as __working code__.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using `applyForward`? You have to add it first.

In your renderer:

```java
Window win;
public MyRenderer(Window w){
    super();
    this.win = w;
}
@Override
public void render(Listitem item, MyObject data, int index) throws Exception {
    .
    .
    .
    Listcell cell = new Listcell();    
    cell.addForward("onMouseOver", item, "onMouseOverMyCell", data);
    item.appendChild(cell);
}
```

And in your controller:

```java
public void onMouseOverMyCell(Event event) throws Exception   {
       System.out.println("There was an event :->" + event.getName());
       Component component = event.getTarget(); //      
       Listcell lc = (Listcell) event.getTarget(); //     
       System.out.println(lc.getLabel().toString());   
}
```

There is also a workaround... you can add a class to your `Listcell` and then catch the event with the listen annotation:

```java
Window win;
public MyRenderer(Window w){
    super();
    this.win = w;
}
@Override
public void render(Listitem item, MyObject data, int index) throws Exception {
    .
    .
    .
    Listcell cell = new Listcell();    
    cell.setClass("mouseOverCell");
    item.appendChild(cell);
}
```

In your controller:

```java
@Listen("onMouseOver = #myListBoxId .mouseOverCell")
public void onMouseOverMyCell(Event event) throws Exception   {
       System.out.println("There was an event :->" + event.getName());
       Component component = event.getTarget(); //      
       Listcell lc = (Listcell) event.getTarget(); //     
       System.out.println(lc.getLabel().toString());   
}
```

---

### EDIT

I didn't specified it, but it's a very important information. You have to wire your event listeners in the renderer to the component using:

```java
Selectors.wireComponents(item, win, false);
Selectors.wireEventListeners(item, win);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but neither approach worked. I am still unable to get the event passed to the handler method.

Comment: Probably I understood which is your problem. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Sorry @Narmer but it appears as if I am missing something more. I added the two lines given and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you wired a onMouseOver listener to the window? If this is the case try to remove it and rerun the above code